# How to set initial approver with apex?

Tags: apex, approval-process

Requirement: Dynamically set approvers for step 1 and step 2 of an approval process. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

- How many approvers: Changes every time for both step one and two.
- Who are the approvers also changes every time.

The data and information that determines who approves what is held in other locations and now in our records that needs approval.

I've been coding stuff, probably going to call it from an lwc....but i know i already goofed Because of the fact it's only setting for the `setNextApproverIds`....instead of the initial approvers.

```apex
public without sharing class IGT_QuoteScenarioApprovalProcess {
    final static string PROCESS_NAME = 'Scenario_Exception';
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
    public static boolean createApprovalSteps(string quoteId, string userId) {
        List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> approvalRequestList = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();
        List<Approval.ProcessResult> results = new List<Approval.ProcessResult>();
        List<Id> quoteIdList = new List<Id>();
        set<Id> segmentApproverIdSet = new set<Id>();
        set<Id> themeApproverIdSet = new set<Id>();
        boolean returnValue;

        segmentApproverIdSet = segmentOwnerApprovers(quoteId);
        themeApproverIdSet = themeOwnerApprovers(quoteId);

        quoteIdList.add(quoteId);

        /**
         * First step approvers. 
         * 
         */
        for(string segmentSet : segmentApproverIdSet){
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest approvalSegmentRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            approvalSegmentRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval from Segment Owner.');
            approvalSegmentRequest.setObjectId(quoteId);
            approvalSegmentRequest.setSubmitterId(userId); 
            approvalSegmentRequest.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(PROCESS_NAME);
            approvalSegmentRequest.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
            approvalSegmentRequest.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{segmentSet});
            approvalRequestList.add(approvalSegmentRequest);
        }

        /**
         * this is for my second step of approvers.
         * 
         */
        for(string themeSet : themeApproverIdSet){
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest approvalThemeRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            approvalThemeRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval from theme Owner.');
            approvalThemeRequest.setObjectId(quoteId);
            approvalThemeRequest.setSubmitterId(userId); 
            approvalThemeRequest.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(PROCESS_NAME);
            approvalThemeRequest.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
            approvalThemeRequest.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{themeSet});
            approvalRequestList.add(approvalThemeRequest);
        }

        try {
            results = Approval.process(approvalRequestList);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        for(Approval.ProcessResult res : results){
            if(res.isSuccess()) {
                returnValue = true;
            } else {
                returnValue = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * retrieve segment owners for first step
     */
    public static set<Id> segmentOwnerApprovers(string quoteId){
        Set<String> approverSet = new Set<String>();
        Set<Id> approverIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Product2> productsToApprove = new List<Product2>();
        List<User> approverIds = new List<User>();

        productsToApprove = [SELECT Theme__r.Segment__c, RTS__c, Pilot__c, Pre_Release__c, Pre_Sale__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT To_Theme__c FROM Theme_Conversion__c WHERE Sales_Toolkit__c =:quoteId)];

        for(Product2 prods : productsToApprove){
            if(prods.RTS__c == TRUE){
                scenarioRTSException__c rts =  scenarioRTSException__c.getValues(prods.Theme__r.Segment__c);
                string rtsApprover = rts.Approver_One__c;
                approverSet.add(rtsApprover);
            }
            if(prods.Pilot__c == TRUE){
                scenarioPilotBuild__c pBuild =  scenarioPilotBuild__c.getValues(prods.Theme__r.Segment__c);
                string pBuildApprover = pBuild.Approver_One__c;
                approverSet.add(pBuildApprover);
            }
            if(prods.Pre_Release__c == TRUE){
                scenarioPreRelease__c preRelease =  scenarioPreRelease__c.getValues(prods.Theme__r.Segment__c);
                string preReleaseApprover = preRelease.Approver_One__c;
                approverSet.add(preReleaseApprover);
            }
            if(prods.Pre_Sale__c == TRUE){
                scenarioPreSale__c preSale =  scenarioPreSale__c.getValues(prods.Theme__r.Segment__c);
                string preSaleApprover = preSale.Approver_One__c;
                approverSet.add(preSaleApprover);
            }
        }
        approverIds = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE FederationIdentifier IN: approverSet];
            
        for(User record: approverIds){
            approverIdSet.add(record.Id);
        }
        return approverIdSet;
    }

     /**
     * retrieve theme owners for second step
     */
     public static set<Id> themeOwnerApprovers(string quoteId){
         Set<Id> approverIdSet = new Set<Id>();
         List<Theme_Conversion__c> productsToApprove = new List<Theme_Conversion__c>();

         productsToApprove = [SELECT To_Actual_Theme__r.OwnerId FROM Theme_Conversion__c WHERE Sales_Toolkit__c =:quoteId 
                            AND (To_Theme__r.RTS__c = TRUE OR To_Theme__r.Pre_Release__c = TRUE
                                OR To_Theme__r.Pilot__c = TRUE OR To_Theme__r.Pre_Sale__c = TRUE)];

         /**
          * remove duplicates
          */
          for(Theme_Conversion__c record: productsToApprove){
              approverIdSet.add(record.To_Actual_Theme__r.OwnerId);
          }
          return approverIdSet;
      }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "...it's only setting for the `setNextApproverIds`....instead of the initial approvers?"

Answer (score 2):

try something like that:

```java
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> approvalRequests = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

List<User> nextApprover = [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT 5]; // Business logic here

    Id objectId = 'someId';

    for (User nextApprover : nextApprover) {
        //Class to submit a record for approval.
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest approvalRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        //Sets the comments to be added to the approval request
        approvalRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
        //Sets the ID of the record to be submitted for approval. For example, it can specify
        // an account, contact, or custom object record.
        approvalRequest.setObjectId(objectId);
        //If the next step in your approval process is another Apex approval process, you specify
        // exactly one user ID as the next approver. If not, you cannot specify a user ID and this
        // method must be null
        approvalRequest.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{nextApprover.Id});

        approvalRequests.add(approvalRequest);
    }
}

Approval.process(approvalRequests);
```

Unfortunately, `setNextApprovers` takes only one Id.

> If the next step in your approval process is another Apex approval process, you **specify exactly one user ID as the next approver**. If not, you cannot specify a user ID and this method must be null.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ProcessRequest.htm#apex_Approval_ProcessRequest_setNextApproverIds

**However, you can invoke it in the loop as in the code above.**

More details here: https://salesforceprofs.com/approval-process-with-dynamic-multiple-approvers/